# "Chinese cuisine" VS "the Chinese cuisine"

Tags: definite-article

> 1. The work reflects Yuan's "orthodox" literati stance on Chinese cuisine, which derided the opulent displays and dishes in banquets of his time. [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suiyuan_shidan)

or

> 2. The work reflects Yuan's "orthodox" literati stance on ***the*** Chinese cuisine, which derided the opulent displays and dishes in banquets of his time.

My puzzlement is whether "the" before Chinese cuisine is a must-have, optional or a must-not-have.

I don't know why I have the inclination to add "the". Maybe it is because I thought Chinese cuisine is a particular kind of food.

Comment: I moved your link to the first example, as that is what Wikipedia used. Could you explain why you are considering using "the"?

Comment: @user3169 I give a rough explanation. I am really sorry I cannot find a firm reason for the adding of the.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is that locutions such as *Chinese cuisine*, *French cuisine*, *Russian cuisine* etc. just like *Chinese culture*, *French culture*, *Russian culture* etc. in general, when talking about the kind of food and dishes eaten in those regions, do not take definite articles. Here are some examples:

> I'm a huge fan of **French cuisine**.
>
> I'm a huge fan of **French culture**.
>
> There are more than eight types of **Chinese cuisine**. ([source](https://eatsiptrip.10best.com/2018/08/10/a-provincial-guide-to-chinas-8-culinary-traditions/))
>
> **Chinese culture** is one of the world's oldest cultures, originating thousands of years ago. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_culture))

Perhaps, the only time you would use a definite article would be in situations where you're comparing a specific instance of a certain culture to another specific instance of that same culture. For example:

> **The French culture** in Quebec is very different from **the French culture** in France.
>
> How is **the Chinese cuisine** popular among Chinese people living in Manhattan different from **the traditional Chinese cuisine** popular in China?